# add Class in match consecutive div using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have to `addCass` on div match consecutive. I have used jquery `nextAll` but it is also highlighting even if did not follow the match div. The last div with text `"a"` should not be part of nextAll

```js
$('a').click(function(){
$(this).parent().nextAll('.abc').addClass('active')
})
```

```css
.active{color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="abc">
    <a>click </a>
</div>

<div class="abc">
    abc
</div>
<div class="abc">
    abc
</div>

<div class="xyz">
    xyz
</div>

<div class="abc">
    a
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.nextUntil()` and `:not()` :

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().nextUntil(':not(.abc)').addClass('active')
})
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jLgxokbp/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter on text use `contains`. Your code selects all with the class abc.

```js
$('a').click(function(){
$(this).parent().nextAll(':contains("abc")').addClass('active')
})
```

```css
.active{color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="abc">
    <a>click </a>
</div>

<div class="abc">
    abc
</div>
<div class="abc">
    abc
</div>

<div class="xyz">
    xyz
</div>

<div class="abc">
    a
</div>
```